# Verify a property of limits

Tags: calculus, limits

Is it generally true that for two functions $f$ and $g$,
$$\lim_{x \to g(a)}{f(x)} = \lim_{x \to a}{f(g(x))}$$
as long as both exist?
This seems to be true when $f$ is continuous at $g(a)$ and $f \circ g$ at $a$, but is true in general? And is continuity of $f$ at $g(a)$ equivalent to continuity of $f \circ g$ at $a$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to g(a)}f(x) = \displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}f(g(x))$ is not true in general, even if both limits exist.

Consider what happens when $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = \lceil x^2 \rceil$, and $a = 0$.

We have $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to g(a)}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}x = 0$, but $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}f(g(x)) = \lim_{x \to 0}\lceil x^2 \rceil = 1$.

Also, from this example, you can see that $f(x) = x$ is continuous at $g(0) = 0$, but $f(g(x))$ is not continuous at $0$. So, continuity of $f$ at $g(a)$ is not equivalent to continuity of $f \circ g$ at $a$.

Comment: Do you know any conditions which guarantee both limits to be equal?

Comment: @Simeon: the conditions are given in answer by Idris. The only point you need to ensure is that $g(x) \neq g(a)$ in some deleted neighborhood of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

If $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)=A $$and $$\lim_{y\rightarrow A}f(y)=B,$$ then $$
\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(g(x))=B,$$ provided $$(f\circ g)(x)$$ is well defined and $g$
does not attain $A$ in a deleted neighborhood of $a.$